# linux' date command returns weird error regarding single quotes

Tags: bash, shell, variables, command-line

I have the following command to convert a date to `epoch`, once a check has succeeded

```
if [[ $COMMENT_DATE == "null" ]]; then COMMENT_TS="null"; else COMMENT_TS=`date -d $COMMENT_DATE '+%s'`; fi
```

this fails with the following error

```
date: invalid date ‘"2022-08-13T10:37:16Z"‘
```

despite the fact that

```
echo $COMMENT_DATE
```

returns no single quotes whatsoever.

I have also tried the following variations when invoking `date` command

```
COMMENT_TS=$(date -d $COMMENT_DATE '+%s')
```

```
COMMENT_TS=`date -d "$COMMENT_DATE" +%s`
```

```
COMMENT_TS=`date -d "$COMMENT_DATE" '+%s'`
```

Is there any sane solution to this before resorting to absurdities such as removing first and last characters from `$COMMENT_DATE` variable?

This runs on a Github Actions step FWIW, the `shell` being `bash`

Comment: what does `declare -p COMMENT_DATE` show?

Comment: I can generate the same error if I start with `COMMENT_DATE='"2022-08-13T10:37:16Z"'` (the double quotes are part of the data); if I start with `COMMENT_DATE='2022-08-13T10:37:16Z'`, or `COMMENT_DATE="2022-08-13T10:37:16Z"`, then the script works as expected since there are no embedded (double) quotes; at this point I'd want to go back and look at how `COMMENT_DATE` is being populated

Comment: as for the subject re: 'single quotes' ... `bash` is adding the single quotes for display purposes to delineate the boundaries of the string in question; what's more interesting are the double quotes that are shown here as being part of the actual string

Answer (score 0):

Try these debug techniques:
Add `--debug` to `date` command
Add `set -x` and `set +x` to see what shell is expanding
Run `--version` to `date` command and see if specific issues exist

Good luck!

```
set -x
COMMENT_DATE="2022-08-13T10:37:16Z"
COMMENT_TS=`gdate --debug -d $COMMENT_DATE '+%s'`
gdate --version
set +x
```

Source code for date.c is [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commits/master/src/date.c)

Sample output:

```
++ COMMENT_DATE=2022-08-13T10:37:16Z
+++ gdate --debug -d 2022-08-13T10:37:16Z +%s
date: parsed datetime part: (Y-M-D) 2022-08-13 10:37:16
date: parsed zone part: UTC+00
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (+00)
date: using specified time as starting value: '10:37:16'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2022-08-13 10:37:16 TZ=+00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2022-08-13 10:37:16 TZ=+00' = 1660387036 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1660387036.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-08-13 10:37:16 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2022-08-13 03:37:16 (UTC-07)
gdate: output format: ‘%s’
++ COMMENT_TS=1660387036
++ gdate --version
date (GNU coreutils) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
++ set +x
```